# is it ok to write about your poor economic condition in SOP

Tags: masters, computer-science, statement-of-purpose

I want to pursue my masters in USA. I have completed my bachelors in Electrical Engineering from one of the top colleges in India and have about 4 years of experience in software development.
I will need financial assistance for my masters. My parents are from lower income group. Can i mention the same in my statement of purpose?
I have completed my bachelors on student loans too.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, since decisions about how to distribute financial support will most likely be based on merit rather than need, with the assumption that any admitted student would want as much support as possible. But I would recommend looking into the funding situation before you even apply; many master's programs in the US provide basically zero funding, unfortunately.

Comment: @user37208: And even if there is need-based financial support, it would typically be awarded via a separate process from admission.  The committee reading the admission letter wouldn't be involved in this process, so there'd be no point in mentioning it in the statement of purpose.